# New to ubuntu problem in accessing internet

Tags: internet-connection

I recently moved on from windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin I love every thing about Ubuntu since it was version 5.04 but now when I installed Ubuntu 12.04 I am unable to access my internet.

I configured my IP address, my net-mask, my gateway, my DNS server
and I can see that I get up/down arrow mark symbol in my system tray representing working network but I am actually not able to access any website.

It works fine for me when I ping my ISP's server I get reply well and good I only fail in getting access to website.

Things were pretty simple previously but now I am facing this problem.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you ping to `208.67.222.222` & `8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: i am able to ping my local isp's server my ip address is 192.62.0.87 and my gateway is 192.62.0.1 i am able to ping and get replies. This is annoying me to see my system with out a internet.

Comment: please any help in this regard is greatly heavily appreciated.

Comment: The local isp may not pass your packets to outside world, or there could be problem with DNS server. Please try to ping the ips I have given to you

Comment: ok i will do it today after i go to my place and can let you know tommorow.

Comment: can you add the output of `ifconfig` and `route -n`?

Comment: yeah sure i can do it.

Comment: got it solved after i replaced nameserver address in my resolv.conf with the dns server of my isp.

Comment: How do i make this questions as solved???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by editing `resolv.conf` by adding nameserver with my ISP's DNS server address.

Thanks to all for replying.